# Groovy sort string's by ArrayList

Tags: sorting, groovy

I try to sort string by order from my ArrayList. I little confused how to do that. For example i have my order list :

```
def my_order = ['Version', 'Author', 'Somethink']
def files_sort = pack.files // here have string's to files
```

In `files_sort` have random string like `db/author/test.sql`, `db/Somethink/test1.sql` and a lot of more.
I think the easiest way will by use loop over my files and use sort based on my order_list ? for example :

```
files.sort.each {
   it.sort(here give my_order ??)
}
```

Thanks for tips !

**EDIT :**

input list :

```
def files_to_sort = ['db/author/test1.sql', 'db/author/foo.sql', 'db/version/test1.sql', 'db/Somethink/foo.sql']
```

output list sorted by `my_order` list :

```
def files_after_sort = ['db/version/test1.sql', 'db/author/test1.sql', 'db/author/foo.sql', 'db/Somethink/foo.sql']
```

Comment: What is the input and desired output?

Comment: The input is string which look like : `db/author/test.sql` but `author` is dynamic  and in files_sort get files in random order. In output i want the same string but in order given by `my_order`

Comment: But how one find if particular string is either version, author or something?

Comment: In one string will occur just one word which I have in `my_order`. Strings every time will have the same build look.

Comment: @JohnDoe, please edit your question and provide sample input file list and desired output.

Comment: @daggett here You go.

Comment: You need to sort using a custom comparator that uses the list `my_order` to decide how any two strings compare.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException could you provide any example how to do that ?

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_sorting

Comment: That's cool, so if that way I will get my desired output, then my question is.  How build Comparator with `my_order` ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def files = ['db/author/test1.sql', 'db/author/foo.sql', 'db/version/test1.sql', 'db/Somethink/foo.sql']
//convert array to uppercase values to support ignore-case
def my_order = ['Version', 'Author', 'Somethink'].collect{it.toUpperCase()} 

//closure to calculate sorting index of string `x` 
def my_index = {x->
    x = x.toUpperCase()
    return my_order.findIndexOf{ x.contains(it) }
}
//the compare in sort: first - by index, if index is same then by value itself
files.sort{a,b->  my_index(a)<=>my_index(b) ?: a<=>b }
println files
```

Answer (score 0):

So to get sorted array, I loop over `my_order` and in it again loop over files.

```
my_order.each{ type ->
        files.sort.each{ file ->
            if(file =~ /.*$type.*/){
                println file
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This is not very safe: if you have a file named `db/author/version1.sql` you'll print it twice, I think.